# How to make this Morphological Graph appear on top of 3D Graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have some code where I want to align a `Graph3D` of a river and a `Plot3D` of `GeoElevationData`, but it doesn't really align.

```
parisRiverIncrease = 250;
parisData = 
  GeoElevationData[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}],
    GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"], GeoProjection -> Automatic, 
   UnitSystem -> "Imperial"];
{mi, ma} = QuantityMagnitude[MinMax[parisData]];
parisLevelPlot = 
  ColorReplace[
   ReliefPlot[parisData, PlotRange -> {mi + parisRiverIncrease, ma}], 
   White -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[0.6, 0.807843137254902`, 1.], Opacity[0.2]]];

parisCityDimensions = 
  Dimensions[
   GeoElevationData[
    Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
    GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"]]];

parisFloodPlot = 
  Show[ListPlot3D[
    GeoElevationData[
     Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
     GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"]], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Texture[parisLevelPlot], 
    Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], ImageSize -> 1250, 
    Boxed -> False]];

parisGraph = 
  Graph3D[MorphologicalGraph[
    Thinning[
     DeleteSmallComponents[
      Dilation[
       ColorNegate[
        Binarize[
         Graphics[
          Flatten[Cases[
            GeoGraphics[
             GeoBoundingBox[
              Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}]], 
             GeoBackground -> "VectorMinimal"], 
            water : {Directive[{___, 
                 RGBColor[0.6, 0.807843137254902`, 1.], ___}], ___} :>
              water[[2]], Infinity]]]]], 3]]]]];

parisElevated = 
  Graph3D[EdgeList[parisGraph], 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 100} &, 
     VertexCoordinates /. 
      AbsoluteOptions[parisGraph, VertexCoordinates]]];

Show[parisFloodPlot, parisElevated]
```

Ideally, I want the Morphological graph of the river to be colored and embedded on top of the GeoElevationMap. Code has been taken from https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2964526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align the Graph3D of the river with the `Plot3D` of `GeoElevationData` and have the river embedded on top of the elevation map, you can adjust the positioning and scaling of the `parisElevated graph`. Here's the modified code:

```
parisRiverIncrease = 250;
parisData = GeoElevationData[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}],
  GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"], GeoProjection -> Automatic, UnitSystem -> "Imperial"];
{mi, ma} = QuantityMagnitude[MinMax[parisData]];
parisLevelPlot = ColorReplace[
  ReliefPlot[parisData, PlotRange -> {mi + parisRiverIncrease, ma}], 
  White -> Directive[RGBColor[0.6, 0.807843137254902`, 1.], Opacity[0.2]]];

parisCityDimensions = Dimensions[
  GeoElevationData[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"]]];

parisFloodPlot = Show[ListPlot3D[
  GeoElevationData[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"]],
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Texture[parisLevelPlot],
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], ImageSize -> 1250, Boxed -> False]];

parisGraph = Graph3D[MorphologicalGraph[
  Thinning[
    DeleteSmallComponents[
      Dilation[
        ColorNegate[
          Binarize[
            Graphics[
              Flatten[Cases[
                GeoGraphics[
                  GeoBoundingBox[
                    Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}]], 
                  GeoBackground -> "VectorMinimal"], 
                water : {Directive[{___, RGBColor[0.6, 0.807843137254902`, 1.], ___}], ___} :> water[[2]], Infinity]]]]], 3]]]];

(* Get the bounding box dimensions of the elevation data *)
elevationBoundingBox = 
  GeoBoundingBox[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
    GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"]] // GeoBounds;

(* Scale the parisElevated graph to match the elevation data dimensions *)
parisElevated = 
  Graph3D[EdgeList[parisGraph], 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Rescale[
     Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} &, 
      VertexCoordinates /. 
       AbsoluteOptions[parisGraph, VertexCoordinates]], {elevationBoundingBox[[1, 1]], 
      elevationBoundingBox[[2, 1]]}, {elevationBoundingBox[[1, 2]], 
      elevationBoundingBox[[2, 2]]}]];

(* Shift the parisElevated graph vertically to embed it on top of the elevation plot *)
parisElevated = Graph3D[EdgeList[parisElevated], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 100} &, VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[parisElevated, VertexCoordinates]]];

Show[parisFloodPlot, parisElevated]
```